# How to enable RockMargin2015 in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, add-on

I installed the plugin, but it is disabled automaticly. I could not find a way to enable it. Does anyone know?

[image]

Comment: Any message when you hover mouse over the Enable button?

Comment: Wow, i did not realize that. The message is: This product cannot be enabled or disabled beacause per user extensions are currently not allowed to load. Please check your settings in the Extensions and Updates options.

Comment: I checked "Environment>Extensions and Updates>Load per user extension.....". Then here we go. Thx Sergey Vlasov.